# Every hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Define a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be a set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \phi(x) = 0\}$ where $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an affine function (of the form $\phi(x) = a^Tx - b$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ being constants).

I would like to prove that all hyperplanes are closed, under the assumption that affine functions are continuous.

If $H$ is a hyperplane, then $H = \phi^{-1}(\{0\})$ for some affine function $\phi$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed, and the preimage of any closed subset under a continuous function is closed, we have that $H$ is closed. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.